# is their any function that i can use to read my csv file without any codec error?

Tags: python-3.x, read.csv

Is their any function that i can use to read my csv file without any codec error?

```py
import re
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import contractions
import csv

basicdict = dict()

temp_of_colums = []


def preprocess_data(test):
    
    return test


def load_data():
    sc_posrev = open("literally nothing\IMDBfileted.csv", mode="w", newline="")
    prev = csv.DictWriter(sc_posrev, fieldnames=["review", "sentiment"])
    cs_file = open("literally nothing\IMDB Dataset.csv",
                   mode="r", encoding="cp1252")
    csvfile = csv.DictReader(cs_file, delimiter=",")
    line = 0
    for row in csvfile:
        # print(row)
        kilo = preprocess_data(row["review"])
        print(line)
        if(line == 0):
            prev.writeheader()
        # print(row["review"])
        line += 1
        p = row["sentiment"].lower()
        if(p == "positive"):
            posrevl = []
            prev.writerow({"review": kilo, "sentiment": 1})
        elif(p == "negative"):
            prev.writerow({"review": kilo, "sentiment": 0})
        if(line == 4000):
            break
    cs_file.close()
    sc_posrev.close()


load_data()
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\nothing\literally nothing\stackov.py", line 100, in <module>
    load_data()
  File "d:\nothing\literally nothing\stackov.py", line 80, in load_data
    for row in csvfile:
  File "C:\Users\Varun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\csv.py", line 111, in __next__
    row = next(self.reader)
  File "C:\Users\Varun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 6237: character maps to <undefined>
```

> line 211 refers to my function call and line 80 refers to iterator
> iterating through the row in file it gives error and changing encodings gives me different types of errors

Comment: Please format your code **and** include the full error message.

Comment: i have added full error in the post and csv file is saved in utf-8 encoding

Comment: The code that you posted does not match the error message. Please post the matching code. Also, you claim that the problem is with reading but the error message clearly says that the error is caused by `prev.writerow`.

Comment: sorry for wrong error message, now i have edited the code and it generates the following error unable to write whole code of the preprocess_data() but it just filters the string.